# binding an element of type java.lang.Object

Tags: java, jaxb

I need to modify an element in my xsd, unfortunately the element is of java.lang.Object type.

I tried binding with the following code snippet.

```
 <jxb:bindings>
            <jxb:globalBindings>
                <jxb:javaType name="java.lang.String" xmlType="xsd:anyType"/>
            </jxb:globalBindings>
        </jxb:bindings>
```

But I'm getting the following an error

```
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolErrorListener.throwToolException(ToolErrorListener.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:166)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:184)
**Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: undefined simple type "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType".**
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:82)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.BIGlobalBinding.dispatchGlobalConversions(BIGlobalBinding.java:429)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.promoteGlobalBindings(BGMBuilder.java:257)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.<init>(BGMBuilder.java:174)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.build(BGMBuilder.java:114)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.annotateXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:415)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:462)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:714)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:270)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
```

Can anybody advice me to resolve this issue.

Comment: is your object(XMLRootElement) having an Object as one of its fields ? It would be worthwhile to place actual class here.

Comment: I think that you are trying to apply the java type on complex type instead to a simple type. xs:anyType is an xsd complex type. If you don't put an XSD we could not help you.